# Firebase push notification is not working in android kotlin and PHP

Tags: php, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to send push notification from my android device through my server, so i have wrote kotlin code for getting token from firebase and stored it into my server. next step i wrote php script to fetch stored tokens from my server and send message command to firebase. i have tested the same API using postman and u got the success message

```
{"multicast_id":7524239394194034238,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1587205979775713%03eb2b8403eb2b84"}]}[]
```

but the message is not received in my android application , when i directly send notification from the firebase console the notification is received in my application i think the problem is in my PHP script. i am new to this firebase configuration and PHP help me to complete this one. 
below i'll add my kotlin  code and PHP scripts

**my kotlin file**

```
class myfirebasemessaging: FirebaseMessagingService() {
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    if (remoteMessage!!.notification != null) {
        val title = remoteMessage.notification!!.title
        val body = remoteMessage.notification!!.body

        NotificationHelper.displayNotification(applicationContext, title!!, body!!)
    }
}
}
```

**fetch token from my db**

```
   public function getAllTokens($usertype){

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT token from fcm_token WHERE user_type=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $usertype);
    $stmt->execute();

     //$stmt->bind_result($token);
     $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $tokens = array(); 

    while($token = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        array_push($tokens, $token['token']);

    }


    return $tokens;

}
```

**Firebase send PHP**

```
class Firebase {

public function send($registration_ids, $message) {
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'notification' => $message,
    );

    return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
}

/*
* This function will make the actuall curl request to firebase server
* and then the message is sent 
*/
private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

    //importing the constant files
    require_once '../Constants.php';

    //firebase server url to send the curl request
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    //building headers for the request
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    //Initializing curl to open a connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Setting the curl url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //setting the method as post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    //adding headers 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //disabling ssl support
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //adding the fields in json format 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    //finally executing the curl request 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    //Now close the connection
    curl_close($ch);

    //and return the result 
    return $result;

}
}
```

**sett message PHP**

```
<?php 

class Push {
//notification title
private $title;

//notification message 
private $message;

//notification image url 
private $image;

//initializing values in this constructor
function __construct($title, $message, $image) {
     $this->title = $title;
     $this->message = $message; 
     $this->image = $image; 
}

//getting the push notification
public function getPush() {
    $res = array();
    $res['data']['title'] = $this->title;
    $res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
    $res['data']['image'] = $this->image;
    return $res;
}

}
```

*sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving notification payload on your android app so change your php getPush function to use notification payload:

```
public function getPush() {
    $res = array();
    $res['title'] = $this->title;
    $res['body'] = $this->message;
    $res['image'] = $this->image;
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: again i am getting the same success message but the notification not received in my application

Comment: I've modified my answer, it seems you're already using notification on Firebase class. Also, please post your final request json body.

Comment: Post your code where your Firebase class is initialised.

Comment: try to log data in `getMessage` function in `MyFirebaseMessagingService.kotlin` you might be receiving notification but it is not being shown because the firebase sdk does not know how to handle custom notifications it just works with the default ones being sent from firbase console. it happend to me in the begining

Comment: @shr3jn yes...thanks broi.. now it's working no i received notification in my application thank you so much

Comment: @shr3jn also , once the new notification is came my previous notifications are clearing automatically ,only last notification is shown in my app . i need to view all previous notification if i didn't view my previous one.

Comment: @developer add a "tag" key on your $res array, use a unique value for your tag every time you send a push notification.

Comment: @shr3jn i have used a tag key in in $res array and it's shown multiple notification if the application is in background but in foreground agin it automatically clear previous notification.

Comment: @shr3jn sometimes the notification is not showing , do i need to change anything in my kotlin code?

Comment: @developer You may want to checkout Notification Bundle: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group